# ValueError at /api/users/ Cannot query "samson": Must be "User" instance

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Having issues generating token for a new user on sign up.

During testing on POSTMAN, when I send a POST request to the server, the user gets registered but a token is not generated for the user.

During testing on POSTMAN, when I send a POST request to the server, the user gets registered but a token is not generated for the user.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/users/

Django Version: 3.0
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['phone_verify',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_auth',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'findr']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\Desktop\FinderAPI\findr\views.py", line 133, in post
    Token.objects.filter(user=users).delete()
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1337, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1362, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1271, in build_filter
    self.check_related_objects(join_info.final_field, value, join_info.opts)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1112, in check_related_objects
    self.check_query_object_type(value, opts, field)
  File "C:\Users\UBITEK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1093, in check_query_object_type
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /api/users/
Exception Value: Cannot query "sams": Must be "User" instance.
```

```
models.py
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField('username',max_length=60)
    phone_number = models.CharField('phone_number',max_length=11,unique=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField('staff_status',max_length=6, default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    #key = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)



    objects = models.Manager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

views.py

```py
class UserList(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self,request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            users = serializer.save()
            if users:
                Token.objects.filter(user=users).delete()
                token = Token.objects.create(user=users)
                json = serializer.data
                json['token'] = token.key
                return Response(json, status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
            )
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(min_length=11, required=True, 
    validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(username=validated_data['username'],phone_number=validated_data['phone_number'])
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'phone_number')
```

Comment: change `Token.objects.create(users=users)` to `Token.objects.create(user=users)`.

Comment: Did that. Got this error: "ValueError at /api/users/
Cannot assign "<User: frank>": "Token.user" must be a "User" instance."

Comment: try this: `Token.objects.create(user=request.user)`

Comment: Did that. Got this error: "IntegrityError at /api/users/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user_id'")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for the question: Provide `request.user` to the create method.

`Token.objects.create(user=request.user)`

**From the comments**, that you are getting `IntegrityError at /api/users/ (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user_id'")`. Since `Token` model has `OneToOneField` with the 'User` model, you cannot have a duplicate entry for same user. You have delete the token then create it again. Since you want to create a token for a user you just created, so your post method will be like:

```py
def post(self,request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        users = serializer.save()
        if users:
            Token.objects.filter(user=users).delete()
            token = Token.objects.create(user=users)
            # you can update the token by: token.key = token.generate_key() and then calling save()
            json = serializer.data
            json['token'] = token.key
            return Response(serializer.data, status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I checked this code, and it is working for me. `serializer.save()` will return a user instance and you can pass it to the `create()` method of Token model.

**Edit**
After going through the code, I can say that he was trying to create a custom user model, and the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` was not set correctly. Also the custom model name was `User`. Setting that correctly and changing some more settings (`USERNAME_FIELD` in model) fixed the problem.

Comment: AttributeError at /api/users/
**'Manager' object has no attribute 'delete'**

Comment: my bad, forgot to filter the user. check now.

Comment: Thanks very much, Nalin. I have sent a connection request to you on LinkedIn. I really appreciate you.

Comment: It is still not working. It is not generating a token for each user. It is only generating a token for the superuser....

Comment: it will not generate a token for each user. It will generate token for logged in user. So you want to generate the token for the user that is created?

Comment: Yes... Since the users are going to be registering they will also be needing the token for login.

Comment: finally got the time edit the answer, it should work now.

Comment: It is not working. Getting Value error!                                                        
Error : **ValueError at /api/users/
Cannot query "samson": Must be "User" instance"**

Comment: can you add the error traceback to your question? and update the code if you have changed that. add the models as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204960/discussion-between-nalin-dobhal-and-samson-adejoro).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, @Samson Adejoro.

As @Nalin pointed out you can use `Token.objects.create(user=request.user)`, the problem here is you are trying to create a token to an user already has one. Probably when testing you already created a token to that same user. The `user` is a `OnetoOneField`field within the `Token` model.

From docs:

> A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a
>   ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation
>   will directly return a single object.

Clear the token created the previous token, before assigning a new one.

`Token.objects.filter(user=request.user).delete()`

Comment: Isn't it possible for me to assign a token to a new user on sign up? @Eliakin Costa

Comment: I want the user to have a unique token generated for them on sign up.

Comment: Yes, you can. If you're using a custom model, you do need to add this to your `settings.py` file as `AUTH_USER_MODEL` or just use the `User` model from `django.contrib.auth.models`. @SamsonAdejoro